# How to use PHP's setcookie() function properly

Tags: php, curl, setcookie

I am trying to figure out the proper way to use PHP's setcookie() function for something I am working on. I am creating a mobile friendly site that uses cURL to log into the other site of my choosing (for now at least, planning to let others use once I have this figured out).

I know with cURL, using the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR feature saves all the info into the file of your choosing.

I was using Live HTTP Headers, a plugin for firefox to see what the set-cookie info was for a forum I visit. Some of the stuff was pretty much the same in my cookie.txt file on my site's host.

My question is, how do I properly use setcookie() to mimic the creation of cookies, so that cookies are being stored on the cell phone rather than my site. So when the user goes to my site and signs in, it makes it look like the actual site created a cookie for them. Which then can be used to read and reply to posts?

Here is an example of how the cookie would look using a test site I made, that uses the same forum system.

```
(hashtag) Netscape HTTP Cookie File

(hashtag) http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html

(hashtag) This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

.devilzgsa.com  TRUE    /hf/sandbox/    FALSE   1355868473  mybb[lastvisit] 1324332473

.devilzgsa.com  TRUE    /hf/sandbox/    FALSE   1355868473  mybb[lastactive]    1324332473

(hashtag)HttpOnly_.devilzgsa.com    TRUE    /hf/sandbox/    FALSE   0   sid ce89856cd25682f4f54e3d550c64bb2f

.devilzgsa.com  TRUE    /hf/sandbox/    FALSE   1355868473  loginattempts   1

(hashtag)HttpOnly_.devilzgsa.com    TRUE    /hf/sandbox/    FALSE   1355868473  mybbuser    1_8xLOcIfhncsaaXMvRjwzeDZhElCOyufBxnzixIfj1PhmhzO6XF
```

Basically I figured I just need to make a cookie that has mybb[lastvisit], mybb[lastactive], sid, loginattempts, and mybbuser.

What values would I use in the setcookie()?

How can I get it so when I use cURL the values are automatically placed correctly into the setcookie() function?

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want to create "fake" cookies from your site that the user can then use directly on the other forum site? Because that's not possible. If OTOH the requests will always go through your server and curl, then I see little reason to recreate the exact same cookies for your users in the first place...

Comment: I guess I will be a bit more specific. My site http://www.devilzgsa.com/hf - the login button WILL(havent linked it yet) take a user to a login page where they type their username and password. I then use cURL to log the user into a different site. When they log in, I told the script to create a cookie based on the username.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion would be to *avoid* using setcookie entirely; instead, use sessions (and thus, the convenient `$_SESSION` superglobal) and simply associate the cookies from cURL with the session you have with your user.

Thus, whenever they request a new page, your system can simply retrieve the relevant cookies from the session and re-use them for the request to the third-party server.

Comment: Mind if I ask how I can exactly associate the cookies from cURL into $_Session?


My main reason for asking all of this, I don't want to phish accounts. The way I have it now using the cURL CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR I am basically phishing accounts (I think)? 

I just want it so when someone visits the login page on my mobile site, which uses cURL to log the user into another. It loads the cookie to read threads and post replies to threads.

Comment: You could try using a variation on the [VariableStream wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php) example from the PHP documentation to register a PHP variable as curl's cookie jar - I have no idea whether this would work, but it shouldn't be too hard to try.